# Plot points on an arc

Tags: vb.net

I am making an arc with a triangle fan.  The triangle fan has to have set points for each of the vertices to make the arc shape.  I have found a multitude of docs regarding DrawArc, but that is not what I am after, and cannot find anything on creating "x number of points" across the arc from point A to point B.

It has been several years since my last trig class, so I am hoping someone has an idea of how to increment the x/y location of the points between A-B.  Here is what I have so far:

```
Dim points As Integer = 5 ' the number of points between top and right
Dim radius as Integer = 25

' Center point
Dim cx As Integer = loc.X + (size.Width - (radius))
Dim cy As Integer = loc.Y + thickness

' Top point
Dim x1 As Integer = loc.X + (size.Width - (radius))
Dim y1 As Integer = loc.Y

' Right point
Dim x2 As Integer = loc.X + (size.Width)
Dim y2 As Integer = loc.Y + radius

Dim trifan As New VertexArray(PrimitiveType.TrianglesFan)

trifan .Append(New Vertex(New Vector2f(cx, cy), col2)) ' Center point
trifan .Append(New Vertex(New Vector2f(x1, y1), col1)) ' Top point

For i = 1 To points

    ' append other points here...

Next

trifan .Append(New Vertex(New Vector2f(x2, y2), col1)) ' Right point
```

Comment: Maybe you can remove the computing part and ask on [Math Exchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/) how you can get the coordinates of a point within an arc given its center, top and right point and angle...

Comment: After that you have to calculate your angle as it depends on the number of points you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just posting this here so it will have an answer for others who come across it.  I had a lot of help with this (as recommended) here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1789110/plot-points-on-an-arc

```
    For i = 0 To points - 1

        Dim x As Double
        Dim y As Double
        Dim t As Double = (PI / 2) * (i / points - 1)

        x = cx + Cos(t) * (radius)
        y = cy + Sin(t) * (radius)

        trifan1.Append(New Vertex(New Vector2f(x, y), col1))

    Next
```